# When I make fat Jar, is it ok to use different Scala version in EMR?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compilation

I use Amazon EMR that have Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11.8.
I wonder when I compile and make fat Jar, is it ok to use Scala 2.11.11?

Comment: The short answer is No.

Comment: Try to make fat Jar for the 2.11.8.
I am not sure it will work with sbt-assembly plugin which I suppose you use for making fat jars, but you can try to use `crossScalaVersions` SBT setting, specify there both 2.11.8 and 2.11.11 versions and before running `assembly` task switch to 2.11.8 with help of `++ 2.11.8` as suggested here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Cross-Build.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to be able to build your EMR fat jar with a correct scala version. This is not hard. I suppose you use sbt-assembly for building fat jars. In this case add this line to your `build.sbt`:
`crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.11.11")`

Then in the sbt shell type `reload` to activate this new setting.
Then when you want to assembly a fat jar against 2.11.8 you type in the sbt console following commands:

```
++ 2.11.8
assembly
```

When you want to compile locally for 2.11.11 or to build a fat jar for 2.11.11 you just switch to that version in sbt console. For example:

```
++ 2.11.11
compile
```

I've checked and it works for me. Here is a log from my sbt console:

```
sbt:TestAssembly> ++ 2.11.8
[info] Setting Scala version to 2.11.8 on 1 projects.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to TestAssembly (in build file:/ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/)
sbt:TestAssembly> assembly
[info] Including from cache: scala-library-2.11.8.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] Packaging /ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/target/scala-2.11/testStep.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 29, 2017 12:07:46 PM
sbt:TestAssembly> ++ 2.11.11
[info] Setting Scala version to 2.11.11 on 1 projects.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to TestAssembly (in build file:/ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/)
sbt:TestAssembly> assembly
[info] Updating {file:/ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/}testassembly...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.11' for Scala 2.11.11. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 13.098s.
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Including: scala-library-2.11.11.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: b0a0cc7ec39ca359187a0b24f303c376b1f2d71f
[info] Packaging /ssd2/projects/TestAssembly/target/scala-2.11/testStep.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 17 s, completed Nov 29, 2017 12:10:37 PM
sbt:TestAssembly>
```

As you can see it does include proper scala library jar in each case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question. When I build fat Jar by using sbt-assembly, the fat-jar operate well when I use Scala version 2.11.11. e.x) in build.sbt, scalaVersion := "2.11.11". Why this fat Jar operate well in EMR which have scala version 2.11.8? Could you answer about it?

Comment: Probably this can explain some part of the subject: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/binary-compatibility-of-scala-releases.html